# Trigger updates with binding

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Trying to figure out a quick way to have a listbox show the current value as follows where

```
listbox is bound to a ObservableCollection<TypeA>
```

and TypeA.ToString() return TypeA.Name

and selecting an item in the listbox shows the TypeA fields in some textboxes for editing

Updating TypeA.Name does not update the values shown in listbox ?

How do i notify the listbox to get the current values ?

updating the listbox while the values are changing in the textbox will be even better !!

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by binding the textboxes to the selected item in the listbox, like this:

```
<ListBox Name="listBox">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>


<TextBox Name="tbName" Text="{Binding ElementName=listBox, Path=SelectedItem.Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
<TextBox Name="tbField2" Text="{Binding ElementName=listBox, Path=SelectedItem.Field2, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
<TextBox Name="tbField3" Text="{Binding ElementName=listBox, Path=SelectedItem.Field3, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

When you change the text in the textboxes the selected item in the listbox will update.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the element binding between listbox and textbox.

```
<TextBox Name="txtName"/>
<ListBoxItem SelectedItem = "{Binding ElementName=txtName, Path=Text}"/>
```